# segmentation fault with big array size

Tags: c++, c

The following piece of code compiles and runs without any problems:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 1000000

int main( void ){

  bool num[N];
  bool *p;
  for( p = num; p < &num[N]; )
    *p++ = true;
}
```

If, however, the value of N gets 10 times bigger (extra 0 -- ten million instead of one million),

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10000000

int main( void ){

  bool num[N];
  bool *p;
  for( p = num; p < &num[N]; )
    *p++ = true;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault on the line beginning with `for`. What is going on here? I don't see anything special about going from 1000000 to 10000000 (million to ten million).

Comment: Which OS ? And what's your stack size limitation ? (`ulimit -a` under linux)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, I now see that the problem is that the stack size has been exceeded.

Comment: @Pierre Thanks -- I see that the problem is with the stack size limit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dmitry Yes - that's it! Stack errors are notoriously hard to catch in C, especially when the allocation is done statically.